# Adding space in a string jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanto to insert a space at the start of my string
Example:

```
MySite
   MySite (I want this)
```

I have tried in this mode but nothing

```
txt="    "+v.text();
```

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm unclear what you want to achieve. Show us the before and after string. If you mean you want to prepend a string with a space, the code you posted is correct (though I don't know why you included five spaces rather than just one).

Comment: remember that html browsers fold multiple adjacent whitespaces into one

Comment: can you do that in `css` instead?

Comment: Use &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MySite

Comment: and what is the context for this? you only want your txt var to have this spaces or is it inside some kind of html structure?

Comment: You need to provide more information in order to obtain relevant answers.

Comment: Because I have to insert this text align to my select, the select list has an image and some text I want to align text of the selected item and the list of the select the only way is to adding space because I'm using a plugin jquery selectbox and with the text-indent indent the image too and isn't the effect that I want

Comment: jsfiddle.net/6qrHq In this page you can see the code but you can't see the image that is before every item of the select list and every text of the select list is moved about 15px to the left

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution is to fill the spaces with `&nbsp;` entities, but if you have to achieve this effect just for styling/visualization purpose, then wrap that line in a proper tag and use some CSS instead (e.g. `text-indent` property)

if you have to indent text inside a select (as I guess reading your previous answer) you may want to wrap your options inside an `optgroup` element (and give it some padding)

Comment: I can't because the text-indent indent the image that I added into the span of my text and I wanto to align only my text and adding some spaces I believe that is more easy

Comment: Alessandro, please fill a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with some actual content/markup so to see what effect you have to accomplish -  Fabrizio

Comment: you could use some other data just to show your markup... a simple representative example. anyway, since your main purpose is text-aligning, the `&nbsp;` entities are not the right solution in this case.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6qrHq/ In this page you can see the code but you can't see the image that is before every item of the select list and every text of the select list is moved about 15px to the left

Comment: The real effect is not visible: if your select is transformed in some other structure, just inspect the markup returned by the plugin and try to apply a text-indent or a padding-left to those elements

Comment: It works! I have modified the css adding this:text-indent:11px; into the selected item, perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Try :

```
 txt="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+v.text();
```

The other good solution would be to use div with some style set on it.

```
 <div style='margin-left:15px' id='main_text'></div>
```

You could use jQuery to place txt in the div.

```
     txt= v.text();
     $('#main_text').html(txt);
```

Comment: In fact `"&nbsp; &nbsp; "` will do it because the spaces between the `&nbsp;`-s.. just a minor tweak

Comment: No in my select return me:"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MySite, It doesn't convert into blank spaces

Comment: jsfiddle.net/6qrHq In this page you can see the code but you can't see the image that is before every item of the select list and every text of the select list is moved about 15px to the left

Answer (score 1):

```
var str2 = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Here goes your string with spaces";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions below :-

```
1. txt="<pre>    </pre>"+v.text();


2. txt="<span style='margin-left:15px'></span>"+v.text();
```